# I am confused with the maximum operating frequency calculation of the circuit

Tags: fpga, flipflop, multiplexer

So, according to my understanding, the max operating freq has the setup time hold time and logic delay and also the clock to output delay...

So my answer is **tclk = (tsu+tco) + tlogic + (tsu+tco) = 2+5+3+2+5 = 17ns**

But, I am not sure if I have to consider the tco of the last flipflop please give me a clarification.

Given that both DFFs have clock-to-output tCO delay of 5ns and a setup time tSU of 2ns. and a propagation delay of 3ns for signals passing the multiplexer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's consider a simple register-to-register transfer (ignoring the feedback path in your diagram).

Looking at the second flop, in order to be clocked correctly, the signal at the data input `FF2.D` must arrive at least one setup time \$(t_\mathrm{su[ff2]})\$ before the clock edge at `FF2.C`.

Including the logic cloud, that means the data must be visible on the output of `FF1.Q` at least \$(t_\mathrm{logic} + t_\mathrm{su[ff2]})\$ before the clock edge at `FF2.C`.

Now consider the first flop. The output `FF1.Q` does not update until one clock-to-output \$(t_\mathrm{co[ff1]})\$ time after the clock edge on `FF1.C`. If we assume that there is zero skew between the clocks of both registers, then that means from the launch clock edge to the latch clock edge, in order to meet timing requirements there must be at minimum:

$$t_\mathrm{period} = (t_{\mathrm{co[ff1]}} + t_{\mathrm{logic}} + t_{\mathrm{su[ff2]}})$$

The maximum frequency \$(f_\mathrm{max})\$ is will be one over this period.

---

Now consider your diagram itself. This is a little more complicated, because there are actually two timing paths because there is a feedback loop from the second flop output back to itself. However this doesn't actually change the analysis that much. You simply consider both paths, and then find the maximum.

[image: Two timing paths, one for FF1 to FF2, one for FF2 to FF2]

For the top path, we have, as before:
$$t_\mathrm{period[path1]} = (t_\mathrm{\mathrm{co[ff1]}} + t_\mathrm{\mathrm{logic}} + t_\mathrm{\mathrm{su[ff2]}})$$

For the bottom path, we have:

$$t_\mathrm{period[path2]} = (t_\mathrm{\mathrm{co[ff2]}} + t_\mathrm{\mathrm{logic}} + t_\mathrm{\mathrm{su[ff2]}})$$

Then:

$$t_\mathrm{period} = \max\left(t_\mathrm{period[path1]}, t_\mathrm{period[path2]}\right)$$

From your numbers, given both flops have the same \$t_\mathrm{co}\$, and only one \$t_\mathrm{logic}\$ is given, both paths have the same timing requirements.